# TaskQueue.php Error - Laravel 5 & Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, forge

When running any Posts and Model::create function within Laravel I am being greeted with the below error;

```
FatalErrorException in TaskQueue.php line 13:
Interface 'GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueueInterface' not found
```

This was working perfectly fine on my local machine but as soon as the website was put onto a server with Forge it has started to show this error.

It looks like the server is trying to use the Queue function with Laravel but my code doesn't ever make use of this;

```php
public function postCreateCustomer(){
        $input = Request::all();

        $customer = Customers::create([
            'customer_name'      => $input['customer_name'],
            'customer_url'     => $input['customer_url']
        ]);

        $password = str_random(8);
        $pass = Hash::make($password);

        $user = User::create([
            'name'      => $input['name'],
            'email'     => $input['email'],
            'password'  => $pass,
            'user_type' => 3,
            'active_customer' => $customer->id,
        ]);

        Access::create([
            'user_id'     => $user->id,
            'customer_id' => $customer->id
        ]);

        $the_content = '<p>Hello '.$input['name'].' ('.$input['customer_name'].'),</p>
        <p>Thank you for creating an account. </p>
        <p>Your login details are listed below;</p>
        <p><strong>Username</strong>: '.$input['email'].'<p>
        <p><strong>Password</strong>: '.$password.'<p>';

        $contactEmail = $input['email'];
        Mail::send('emails.default', ['the_content' => $the_content, 'the_heading' => 'Customer Account Created'], function ($message) use ($contactEmail) {
            $message->subject("Customer Account Created");
            $message->to($contactEmail);
        });

        Session::flash('success_message', 'The new customer has been created.');
        return Redirect::to('/customers');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I found that was caused by the class "TaskQueueInterface" had not be found.

The following is my solution:

1. open the folder: /vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src
2. edit TaskQueue.php
3. modify "class TaskQueue implements TaskQueueInterface" to "class TaskQueue"

After doing the above, stay tuned for the official release.

Comment: Maybe that's its author's careless mistake because I can't find that class.